# Проблема с сайтом-компилятором

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

При нажатии на кнопку Run вместо результата я получаю ошибку [object OBJECT]. Код который ответственен за отправку и получение данных следующий:

---

```
function run() {
  var cmd = "g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main_prog && echo 'Done."
    + " Program output is:\n' && ./main_prog && echo \"\nExit code: $?\"";
  var output = $("#output");
  output.text('');
  var to_compile = {
    "src": code.getValue(),
    "cmd": cmd,
  };
  output.text("Compiling, Please Wait...");
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/compile",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(to_compile),
    contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text"
  }).done(function (data) {
    output.text(data);
  }).fail(function (data) {
    output.text("Server error: " + data);
  });
};
```

---

Помогите пожалуйста!
[image: демонстрация ошибки]

Comment: Замените `output.text("Server error: " + data);` на `output.text("Server error: " + JSON.stringify(data));`. Сайт этот не может вывести в консоль объект, который приходит

Comment: Здравствуйте! 
Я попробовал изменить данный фрагмент кода. В итоге сайт прекратил подавать признаки работы (сколько бы раз я не нажимал кнопку run ничего не меняется).

Comment: С вашей помощью сайт был атакован успешно умер, с чем вас и поздравляю! )) А если серьезно, то поставьте себе нормальную IDE, где будет у вас подсветка синтаксиса кода и тестируйте приложение в обычном браузере, где так же все ошибки будут видны, включаю вывод объектов, массивов и т.д.

Comment: Вы натолкнули меня на мысль проверить все ли файлы есть (ибо редактор тут ace.js, а тема должна быть Textmate). Спасибо вам за помощь. Когда решу проблему - закрою тему. Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо что помогли, как выяснилось не хватает некоторых файлов, что и стало виновником торжества.